# The derivation and simplification of the functions HeavisideTheta and Dirac

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I encounter some problems, can you help me? Thanks.

1. Step (1) gives the expected result `3 DiracDelta[x]`, why (2) and (3)
   can not give expected result `HeavisideTheta[x]`?
2. I have assumed the name "q" is a real constant, why (4) will not give
   the result `q*DiracDelta[x]`?
3. How to simplify (5) and make the result `HeavisideTheta[x]` out?

Thanks again for your any suggestions.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
$Assumptions = Element[q, Reals]; (*or any constant that's not equal to zero*)
DiracDelta[x/3]  (*1*)
HeavisideTheta[x/3] (*2*)
HeavisideTheta[x/3] // Simplify (*3*)
DiracDelta[x/q] (*4*)
HeavisideTheta[x/q] (*5*)
```

Result:

```
3 DiracDelta[x]
HeavisideTheta[x/3]
HeavisideTheta[x/3] (*Why is it not HeavisideTheta[x]*)
DiracDelta[x/q]     (*Why not q*DiracDelta[x], how to get*)
HeavisideTheta[x/q] (*Why not HeavisideTheta[x], how to get*)
```

Comment: Notice, however, `$Assumptions = a > 0; Integrate[
 f[x] DiracDelta[x/a], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` correctly gives `a f[0]`.

Comment: @yarchik: This integral makes no sense in math (e.g. see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function) for info). That was discussed here many times.

Comment: Assuming `Element[q, Reals]`, you allow `q==0`. but division by `0` is impossible.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, this was discussed many times here, but that does not make the statement "This integral makes no sense in math" any more correct! Also in your link, the integral is used (see formula (2) and example dirac-function)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Did you read "The simplest examples of generalized functions are those generated by locally integrable functions on :" before formula (2) and  the text under (2)?

Comment: @user64494 Yes I did

Comment: @UlrichNeumann:  Did you understand that the integrand in (2) is a usual function, not a distribution? Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 I understand it well: Not the integrand, only the part `f[ ...]` has to be integrable.

Comment: Regarding the integration example provided by @yarchik, Mathematica is tacitly assuming the unknown function `f` is in fact integrable. I hope that clarifies matters, at least outside of a singularly singular set...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann:  Sorry, you don't ground " only the part f[ ...] has to be integrable" and this doesn't correspond to reality: $\varphi$ is an infinitely differentiable function with a compact support. Therefore, the integrand is a usual function. Formula (2) stands for the definition of the generalized function whicih is generated by $f$. I repeat that $\delta$-distribution is not generated by any usual function. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need again.

Comment: @DanielLichblau:  You wrote "I hope that clarifies matters, at least outside of a singularly singular set..."  What are  "matters"? What is  "a singularity singular set"? TIA. I repeat the integral written by yarchik makes no sense in math.

Comment: @user64494 I don't ground something, I only recall what your link describes: "Generalized functions definable by (2) in terms of locally integrable functions  f on O are called regular generalized functions on  O" ( see also DanielLichtblau's comment)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Let us read the complete and exact quote "Generalized functions definable by (2) in terms of locally integrable functions $f$ on $O$ are called regular generalized functions on  $O$ ; the remaining generalized functions are called singular. There is a one-to-one correspondence between locally integrable functions on  $O$ and regular generalized functions on $O$ . In this sense, the "ordinary" , that is, locally integrable on $O$, functions are (regular) generalized functions in $D'(O)$.

An example of a singular generalized function on  is the Dirac -function".

Comment: The integral is well defined, in the sense of calculus of distributions, provided `f` is well behaved at the origin, and `a` is a nonzero real. By "clarifies matters" I mean "clarifies any issues raised about this integral" (it is an English colloquialism and perhaps does not translate well).

Comment: @DanielLichblau: (i) Sorry, you don't answer "What is "a singularly singular set"?". (ii} Your statement "The integral is well defined, in the sense of calculus of distributions, provided f is well behaved at the origin, and a is a nonzero real" is ungrounded.

Comment: (1) @user64494 It's the set of forum participants who seem not to be finding references to the math, and also not able to politely request such. Kammler's "First Course in Fourier Analysis" ch 7, Kanwal's "Generalized Functions Theory and Techbnique" ch 3 sec 6, Lancaster and Salkauskas "Transfor Methods in Applied Mathematics" ch 6 sec 6 might be a few reasonable ones to look at.

Comment: (2)  Also: I made a statement about the math and the underlying assumptions in the Mathematica treatment thereof. It's not clear to me what needs to be grounded. The math part one can check. The Mathematica part relies on me knowing what it does. In this case I have a fair idea of what it does, having spent some time in that neck of the code.

Comment: @user 64494 Another nice reference, this time from the analysis side, is "Introductory Real Analysis" by A. N. Kolmogorov and S. V. Fomin, chapter 5 sections 20 and 21. The upshot is that the definite integral is simply defined by the sifting property of the Dirac delta linear functional, as a limit of traditional integrals.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau:(i) I looked in "Introductory Real Analysis" by A. N. Kolmogorov and S. V. Fomin (more exactly, in its original in Russian) and found there only $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\varphi(x)\,dx$  which defines a generalized function associated with a usual function $f(x)$.(ii) I looked in Kammler's "First Course in Fourier Analysis" and found there the same. I'd like to quote "It is easy to show that there is no ordinary piecewise continuous function $\delta$ for which $\delta(\phi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)\phi(x)\,dx$". It seems you didn't carefully read those books.

Comment: @user64494 You apparently missed the point in both: They are defining the integral of the Dirac delta generalized function. It is clear that no "ordinary piecewise continuous function" can serve as the Dirac delta functional. It is also clear that the Dirac delta is not an ordinary piecewise continuous function. Are you seriously not aware that these are definitions of an integral as a limit of sequences of ordinary integrals?

Comment: See K&F section 21.2 examples 1 and 2 (at least in the translated English version). Section 20.3 makes clear that they are defining the definite integral of the delta function against functions in the test spave (denoted K in that text).

Comment: @ 
user64494  The integral of @yarchik makes perfect sense.  See https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Delta-function.  That integral is fully validated there.

Comment: @BillWatts: I see the conclusion "Thus, the delta-function is not an ordinary function in the sense of the classical theory of functions, and is defined in the theory of generalized functions as a singular generalized function, i.e. as the continuous linear functional in the space of infinitely-differentiable functions f of compact support, assigning to f its value at zero: (δ,f)=f(0)." there.

Comment: @user64494 The delta-function doesn't have to be an ordinary function in order for the integrals to be valid.  The very first integral in that paper tells you how to integrate a delta-function and you will not believe it.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: I'd like to notice that "функция"=fuction in Russian original is written in quotes.

Comment: @BillWatts & DanielLichtblau: The question arises: what is the definite integral of a distribution? The Riemann integral is defined as the limit of integral sums. In old books the action of  $\delta$-distribution on a function $f$ was written as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x)\,dx$. In new books this notation is not used.

Comment: What do you think integrating over a space means?  Mathematica believes it.  Physicists believe it.  The Math Stack Exchange folks believe it.  The only one I know who doesn't believe it is you.  It is the indefinite integral of a delta-function that is undefined in physics.  The delta-function is defined by that integral.

Comment: @BillWatts: Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such style. This is neither math nor Mathematica.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you (@user64494) object to the use of the definite integral notation? It is, as several of us point out, well defined (using delta sequences, which are Riemann integrals). It is, as I noted, used in several modern texts. You perhaps prefer the dual pairing notation `<\Delta,f>`? Fine. But that in no way invalidates the integral notation. So why all the fuss? You raise the forum temperature several degrees (pick your preferred scale), and for...what?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau:  Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such manner. This is neither math nor Mathematica.

Comment: Well, after several have explained (with extensive references) both the math and the Mathematica, there is not much left except to try to figure out how you remain confused. This is something that we can drop. It's just that the same (mis-)claims always get repeated later. Anyway, it would be helpful if you simply take the usage of definite integrals with the Dirac delta as definitions of a notation for application of a particular singular linear functional. The theory behind this definition is well established, per references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third expression works with `FullSimplify`

```
HeavisideTheta[x/3] // FullSimplify
(* HeavisideTheta[x] *)
```

As for your last two expressions, q is a variable and you are asking for a simplification that requires a numeric constant.  I don't think any assumption will allow you to satisfy that requirement.  The same requirement exists for the command `Arg`, the only difference is that the documentation for `Arg` tells you that up front.  It is also true for many other Mathematica expressions.

A very dirty workaround that I sometimes use is:

```
DiracDelta[x/E] /. E -> q
(* q DiracDelta[x] *)
```

and

```
(HeavisideTheta[x/E] // FullSimplify) /. E -> q
(* HeavisideTheta[x] *)
```